# read csv file which has columns shuffled

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I m trying to read csv file in databricks using pyspark where it has columns shuffled instead of A ,B, C it will randomly arranged like C,A,B
i tried using map() , it throws error 'cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object'

i need to reshuffle the column correctly using pyspark in databricks.
I refered to the example in https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-map-transformation/ it is not helping to me because i have dataframe created by reading csv file

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

appName = "AddColumnUsingMap"
spark = SparkSession.Builder().appName(appName).getOrCreate()
parentname='xx'
filename='Test (2)'
todayDate='2022-05-24 1:48:42'
extension='.csv'
filePath="dbfs:/mnt/bronze/landing/x/"+parentname+"/"+"current/"+filename+extension

# Formats
read_format = "csv"
write_format = "csv"
claimdenials_df_raw = (spark
                  .read
                  .format(read_format)
                  .option("multiLine", "true")
                  .option("header", "true")
                  .option("escape", '"')
                  .load(filePath))
display(claimdenials_df_raw)
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(claimdenials_df_raw)
def func1(x):
    DenialId=x["Id"]
    PatientFirstName=x["First Name"]
    PatientLastName=x[" Last Name"]
    PatientDateOfBirth=x["Date of Birth"]
    PatientId=x["PatientId"]
    
    return (DenialId,PatientFirstName,PatientLastName,PatientDateOfBirth,PatientId)

rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: func1(x))
print(rdd2.collect())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer rdd to dataframe with correct order.
I am not sure but you can try with rdd2

```
df = rdd2.toDF(["Id", "First Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "PatientId"])
```

Comment: hi @kyungjin Jung , Thank you !! its throwing error in the line where i define the rdd

Answer (score 0):

The `sparkContext.parallelize()` helps us to create an RDD from a **list of elements or a collection**. It is throwing the error `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object` because you are trying to create an RDD by directly passing the dataframe `claimdenials_df_raw`.

So, you need to modify your code as shown below:

```
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(claimdenials_df_raw.collect())
```

- Here `claimdenials_df_raw.collect()` returns a list of all the data of your dataframe. You can pass this list to successfully create an RDD.

```
rdd = claimdenials_df_raw.rdd
```

- Using the above code also gives you an RDD to work with.

The above code helps to overcome the error. You can use the following modified code directly to get `rdd2`:

```
claimdenials_df_raw = (spark 
                  .read 
                  .format(read_format) 
                  .option("multiLine", "true") 
                  .option("header", "true") 
                  .option("escape", '"') 
                  .load(filePath)) 
display(claimdenials_df_raw) 
rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(claimdenials_df_raw.collect()) 
def func1(x): 
    DenialId=x["Id"] 
    PatientFirstName=x["First Name"] 
    PatientLastName=x[" Last Name"] 
    PatientDateOfBirth=x["Date of Birth"] 
    PatientId=x["PatientId"] 
     
    return (DenialId,PatientFirstName,PatientLastName,PatientDateOfBirth,PatientId) 
 
rdd2=rdd.map(lambda x: func1(x)) 
print(rdd2.collect())
```

**Additional approach without RDD:**

Instead of using RDD to shuffle the columns you can simply use `DataFrame.select()` and pass the required order of column names. You can use the following code:

```
claimdenials_df_raw_updated = claimdenials_df_raw.select("Id", "First Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth", "PatientId")

claimdenials_df_raw_updated.show()
```